# Java boolean method with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, boolean

Hey I'm trying to do a for loop inside a method which should return a boolean. However I keep getting an error. Basically the array can get very big and I wish for this to check through the whole array to look for the username and password.

```
public class Users {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String[][] accounts = { { "user1", "pass1" }, { "user2", "pass2" } };

    public Users(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean check() {

        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            if ((username.equals(accounts[i][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[i][1]))) 
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't keep getting "an error".  You are getting ***a very specific error.*** If you are so unfamiliar with programming that you don't understand the error, and you regard it as noise, it does not mean that it is not important.  Actually, it is by far the most important thing.  ***Post it.***

Comment: Just for clarification, `return` statements immediately break out of the method they are in, so when the for loop compares the `username` and `password` with the first `String[]` in `accounts`, whether or not the values are equal, the loop is broken and the method returns.

Comment: And actually no, you are not even getting an error. Your code just does not work the way you expected it to.

Comment: @MikeNakis I believe that that is what they meant by "getting an error;" that their code was not giving them exactly what they wanted.

Comment: Not to mention the use of parallel arrays...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently returning `false` if the first entry in the `accounts` array doesn't match the `username` and `password`.

If you want to check all the accounts, you should return `false` only after the loop is done:

```
public boolean check() {
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if ((username.equals(accounts[i][0])) && (password.equals(accounts[i][1]))) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: in this case it will return true if the first result is correct without checking the other data\

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I believe that's the required behavior. Once a match is found, there is no need to check the rest of the array. If you require that all the elements of the array match, you are requiring that all the elements of the array be identical, which means you don't need the array at all.

Comment: It's depending on the requirement So both of us have correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be as inverse take a look about bellow

```
public class Users {
private String username;
private String password;
private String[][] accounts = { { "user1", "pass1" }, { "user2", "pass2" } };

public Users(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean check() {

    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if ((!username.equals(accounts[i][0]))||(password.equals(accounts[i][1]))) 
            return false;

    }
 return true;
} 

}
```

Okay Let us talk why ?
You said sometimes you will have a big array so if one goes wrong there is no need to continue the loop and it will return false immediately once if there is wrong data , otherwise it will return true;

**UPDATE**
if your loop been like what you did, you are checking if first result is correct
that's why i inverted the loop

Comment: You put `return true;` outside of the `check()` method. That is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean method() { // please note: when this method is called

  int i; // it executes this line

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){  // then it executes this line
       // while this loop is executing it also executes return false statement
        if(i==8){
           return true;
        }
    }

     return false;// then it executes this line

//therefore the boolean value will be false. i mean the returned boolean value and //then it returns true;
}
```

Please clarify if my understanding is wrong?